# hyperlink in bibliography

Tags: hyperref

how do I go about including a hyperlink in the bibliography.  I am trying this and it does not work:

```
@article{pll_wikipedia,
    address = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked\_loop},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    author = {},
    title = {Phase-Locked Loop},
    year = {},
    volume = {},
    number = {},
    pages = {},
    month = {}
}
```

Comment: Which bibliography style are you using?  Some insert hyperlinks automatically; the name of the field for the URL varies, though.  Also, are you including package `hyperref`?

Comment: In addition to dupes, note that `address` is for a physical address of a publisher, and that what you have above is not an `article` but `misc`. (The `article` type is for something like a journal article, which typically has author/title/journal/year/volume/pages.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JosephWright has already commented, the `@article` entry type is not well suited for entries of the type you're displaying. You should probably be using the `@misc` entry type.

Moreover, assuming you'll use the `@misc` entry type, you shouldn't be using the `address` field to store the URL. Instead, you probably want to use the `howpublished` field and encase the URL in a `\url{...}` instruction.

Assuming you're using a bibliography style such as `plainnat`, you might get something like this if you follow these suggestions:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{phase.bib}
@misc{pll_wikipedia,
    howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked\_loop}},
    author = {Publisher},
    note = {Last visited on <insert date here>},
    title = {Phase-Locked Loop},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}  % allow line breaks at hyphens
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{phase}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This helped me to get clickable URL in the bibliography citation list. But since I use Zotero with LyX, and the add-on "BBT" in Zotero, I also had to check one more option in Zotero: Menu, Zotero Preferences / Better BibTeX / Export / [x] Add URLs to BibTeX export: in a URL field. Then it worked!