# Lyx cannot generate hyperlinks as references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, hyperref, lyx

This question is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131929/hyperlink-in-bibliography) one. I have a bibtex file containing a number of references some of which are only links to a number of domains.

The entries in the .bib file are of the form:

```
@Misc{software_module_link,
  HowPublished             = {\url{https://github.com/software}},

  Timestamp                = {2016.05.18}
}
```

The bibliography is generated but the link itself is not clickable. Why? There is also an extra full stop appended to its end.

Comment: Have you checked in the document settings, that hyperref is checked?

Comment: Yes, I've got it running. I'll post an answer later.

Comment: I assume you will not post the answer?!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP never posted the answer as discussed in the comments.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's nothing in this question that is useful to future readers